Second cohomology of $SL(2,13)$ with coefficients in a faithful 6-dimensional irreducible module over $GF(3)$.
Let $G=SL(2,13)$.
Then $G$ has two faithful $6$-dimensional irreducible module over $GF(3)$.
Let $V$ be one of them.
I want to count $H^2(G,V)$ in GAP system.
I have tried the method post in this question In GAP, how to to construct all non-split extensions?.
However, it returns error.
So, how can I count $H^2(G,V)$ in GAP system?
My GAP version is v.4.12.2 (in Windows 10).
My code is:
gap> g:=AtlasGroup("2.L2(13)");
<matrix group of size 2184 with 2 generators>
gap> reps:=IrreducibleRepresentations(g,GF(3));;
gap> mats:=List(GeneratorsOfGroup(g),x->Image(reps[2],x));
[ < immutable compressed matrix 6x6 over GF(3) >, < immutable compressed matrix 6x6 over GF(3) > ]
gap> mo:=GModuleByMats(mats,GF(3));
rec( IsOverFiniteField := true, dimension := 6, field := GF(3),
  generators := [ < immutable compressed matrix 6x6 over GF(3) >, < immutable compressed matrix 6x6 over GF(3) > ],
  isMTXModule := true )
gap> co:=TwoCohomologyGeneric(g,mo);;co.cohomology;
Error, no method found! For debugging hints type ?Recovery from NoMethodFound
Error, no 1st choice method found for `IsomorphismFpGroupByChiefSeries' on 2 arguments at /opt/gap-v4.12.2/.libs/../lib/methsel2.g:249 called from
IsomorphismFpGroupByChiefSeries( G, "F" ) at /opt/gap-v4.12.2/.libs/../lib/gpfpiso.gi:54 called from
IsomorphismFpGroupByChiefSeries( G ) at /opt/gap-v4.12.2/.libs/../lib/gpfpiso.gi:1106 called from
ConfluentMonoidPresentationForGroup( G ) at /opt/gap-v4.12.2/.libs/../lib/twocohom.gi:801 called from
<function "TwoCohomologyGeneric generic, using rewriting system">( <arguments> )
 called from read-eval loop at *stdin*:69
type 'quit;' to quit to outer loop


What error do you get? Which version of GAP are you using?

It seems the GAP command TwoCohomologyGeneric is not implemented for finite matrix groups, but it should work for finite permutation groups, for example.
(According to the documentation here, the command works for all finite groups, but I suppose the input group should be of a specific type.)
So for example, try replacing the beginning of your code with the following:
g := SL(2,13);;
g := Image(IsomorphismPermGroup(g));;

so that g is a permutation group.

It seems that I cannot do this at the beginning. ````gap> g:=SL(2,13);
SL(2,13)
gap> g:=Image(IsomorphismPermGroup(g));
<permutation group of size 26208 with 2 generators>


However, one could put the code g:=Image(IsomorphismPermGroup(g)) after you take the module you wanted. Then everything is fine.

Not really different in practice, just to explain the manual: The issue is that the utility routine ConfluentMonoidPresentationForGroup so far does not work for matrix groups. As soon as this is resolved TwoCohomologyGeneric will also work for matrix groups. That is the reason why the manual does not state it only works for permutation groups (and PcGroups).
